# Trust region subproblem

Tags: numerical-optimization

I'm triying to replicate this paper:
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1818/1/012022/pdf

But I don't know how implement this part:
Find $d_{k}$ such that

$$\min q_{k}(d) \quad \text{such that} \quad ||d|| \le \quad \delta_{k}$$
where
$$_{}() =\frac{1}{2} ‖(_{}) + _{}‖^{2}$$

Comment: There's a huge literature on numerical methods for the trust-region subproblem.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: We tried using Least squares to find $d_{k}$ but it didn't work. Can you please give me the references about how solve it?,